# Summoning a horse that has dyed horse armor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is my current command:

```
/summon horse ~ ~3 ~4 {Tame:1, SaddleItem:{id:saddle,Count:1}, ArmorItem:{id:leather_horse_armor,display:{color:3949738},Count:1}}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: That there are spaces in the NBT part? No idea, you tell me what's wrong with it. Does it give you an error message, does it make your house explode, does it say mean words to you, …?

Comment: i'm trying to get a horse with dyed leather horse armor but when it spawns in i just get a horse with undyed leather horse armor

Comment: That would be a good thing to put into the question.

Comment: @FabianRöling If you look at the edit history you will see that this information was in the title at first. My edit was aimed at making the title easier to understand, but I unwittingly removed helpful information.

Comment: Sorry about that, Ryan. I should have known that that part of the title was helpful for understanding what was wrong with the command you had tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summoned a horse and put blue leather horse armor on it. I then looked at it and pressed <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and got this command copied into my clipboard:

```
/summon minecraft:horse 7.86 63.00 -142.70 {Brain: {memories: {}}, HurtByTimestamp: 0, Tame: 1b, Attributes: [{Base: 26.0d, Name: "generic.maxHealth"}, {Base: 0.0d, Name: "generic.knockbackResistance"}, {Base: 0.3144634919109718d, Name: "generic.movementSpeed"}, {Base: 0.0d, Modifiers: [], Name: "generic.armor"}, {Base: 0.0d, Name: "generic.armorToughness"}, {Base: 16.0d, Modifiers: [{UUIDMost: 7011061429969178561L, UUIDLeast: -6231576989739238927L, Amount: -0.012178698746547666d, Operation: 1, Name: "Random spawn bonus"}], Name: "generic.followRange"}, {Base: 0.0d, Name: "generic.attackKnockback"}, {Base: 0.7635032052473723d, Name: "horse.jumpStrength"}], Invulnerable: 0b, FallFlying: 0b, ForcedAge: 0, PortalCooldown: 0, AbsorptionAmount: 0.0f, Bred: 0b, FallDistance: 0.0f, ArmorItem: {id: "minecraft:leather_horse_armor", Count: 1b, tag: {display: {color: 3949738}}}, InLove: 0, EatingHaystack: 0b, DeathTime: 0s, HandDropChances: [0.085f, 0.085f], PersistenceRequired: 0b, Age: 0, Motion: [0.0d, -0.0784000015258789d, 0.0d], Health: 26.0f, LeftHanded: 0b, Air: 300s, OnGround: 1b, Rotation: [90.44398f, -3.7093549f], HandItems: [{}, {}], Variant: 773, ArmorDropChances: [0.085f, 0.085f, 0.0f, 0.085f], OwnerUUID: <my UUID>, Fire: -1s, ArmorItems: [{}, {}, {id: "minecraft:leather_horse_armor", Count: 1b, tag: {display: {color: 3949738}}}, {}], Temper: 15, CanPickUpLoot: 0b, SaddleItem: {id: "minecraft:saddle", Count: 1b}, HurtTime: 0s}
```

After cleaning the command up a bit, you get this command:

```
/summon horse ~ ~ ~ {ArmorItem:{id:leather_horse_armor,Count:1,tag:{display:{color:3949738}}}}
```

Executing this command summons a tamed horse with a saddle and blue leather horse armor.

Comment: @FabianRöling Did they change something with commands again? When I wrote this answer I tested the command both without the `ArmorItem`-tag and without the `ArmorItems`-tag, neither of those commands worked and both tags were nessessary for this to work. (Your command works now though)